# Facebook v2.0 API - Force initial canvas login to use the 2.0 API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

**Background info:**

I am working on a facebook game that needs to convert to the Facebook v2.0 API in the coming months.  It was made before the 2.0 API conversion, so currently users are logged in under the Facebook 1.0 API.

I have successfully converted over to using the 2.0 API for pretty much all cases, with the exception of sending invite messages to non-users.  Sending an invite under the 2.0 API returns an app scoped user ID for the invited person, not the canonical Facebook ID for that user.

**The Problem:**

When a user logs into the game for the first time, they are logged in under the canonical Facebook ID - NOT the app scoped ID I was given earlier.  This makes tying back the original message that was sent in our database (under an app scoped user ID) to the user that logged in impossible.  All API calls that I have control of are done under the Facebook 2.0 API, however it seems that the initial permissions dialog that comes up when you first click on the app (asking if you want to grant permissions to this app) is managed by Facebook, and uses the 1.0 API for the initial login because it thinks my app is still using the 1.0 API.  As you can see in the following image, it is asking for basic info permissions which was removed in the 2.0 API.

[1.0 Login Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/333jo.png)

**The Question**

Is there any way I can force this initial dialog to use Facebook API 2.0?  This should force an app scoped user ID on new users, and bypass issues with trying to match up two different ids.

For a while, I believe that the app control panel on developers.facebook.com had a slider that let you select which version of the API that you wanted to use for your app, but I can no longer find any settings that let me change this.  Any suggestions on how to deal with this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Just add v2.0 in the call to use the v2.0 login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem was in the getLoginURL function of base_facebook.php to get the correct redirect url.  Changing 'dialog/oauth' to 'v2.1/dialog/oauth' results in a url that looks like this for the initial authorization:

https://www.facebook.com/v2.1/dialog/oauth?client_id=...

This forces the user to get an app scoped user ID on the initial login to the app.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem of the invites, just ask to the facebook graph for the scoped_id you get from the request invites:
facebook.Get("[scoped_id]?fields=id")

and you will get the id used in your app, no matter if this is canonical or scoped.